# Set cookie with path but no expiration date?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I want to setCookie with path but no expiration date. But the syntax is like this in PHP `setCookie(name,value,exp-date,path)` I want `setCookie(name,value,path)` but the PHP wount let me. Or I want to expiration be Session. How its posible?

Comment: Not quite the answer I looking for. I dont want unlimited time to exp-date. I want session cookie, but with different path.

Comment: From the documentation: "If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)." - read it: https://php.net/manual/ro/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setCookie function requires an expiration date, just set it to a far future date such as ten years:

time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)

If you just want to use session variables, use this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

To have the cookie end at the end of the session, use zero for time.

setcookie('COOKIENAME', 'COOKIEVALUE', 0, '/mypath');

Comment: When I write `setcookie(name,value);` it sets my Cookie with expiration date to Session, I want to keep that but shange the path of that Cookie witch by the syntax is after the date and I cant create Cookie with different path whit out changing the exp-date.
Is it posible to keep the exp-date to Session and change the default path?

Comment: Nice. Its easy as that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to save cookie for unlimited time but you can give it a longer time like 10, 15 or 20 years like this.

```
setcookie("your-Cookie-Name","your-Cookie-value",time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)); //it will set cookie for 20 years
```